# Issue related to getScript in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, getscript

I am now facing an issue related to getScript in rails. Actually I am able to pass a variable data to a particular action of my rails controller using the following line in my view.

getScript('/user/out_action.js?pt=' + resulted_time); // resulted_time is the variable name I want to send.

Where 'user' is the controller name and out_action is an action in the controller.
It is completely fine.

Now my problem is that I am unable to send multiple different variable data to the controller action from my view. I am using ruby on rails. I want to pass this data using one single call.

For example I want to pass to another variable like resulted_time using the same call.

Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple you need to enhance your query string like below example. If you are using coffee script below

```
$.getScript('/user/out_action.js?pt=#{resulted_time}&ps=#{resulted_time}');
```

That will insert multiple parameters. For plain javascript, you can use below code.

```
$.getScript('/user/out_action.js?pt='+resulted_time+'&ps='+resulted_time);
```

Let me know if you need more elaboration.

Comment: Thank you @Muaaz ...I have already updated my code using your second approach and it is working.